# How to display date and time in two rows?

Tags: php, html, date

Please, help about formatting date in a .php page:
...return`

```
<div class="date">'.date('d M Y - H:m',$d['dt']).'</div>
```

this id displayed as `21 Dec 2012 - 20:12`

I want first row: `21 Dec 2012`
--------and second: `20:12`

I tried many combinations with `<br/>`, points, brackets...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use two `date()` calls:

```
<div class="date">'.date("d M Y",$d['dt']).'<br />'.date("H:m",$d['dt']).'</div>
```

Or escape properly:

```
date('d M Y <\b\r /> H:m',$d['dt'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use 2 date function:

```
$one = date('d M Y');
$two = date('H:m');


echo "<div class='date'>";
echo $one;
echo "<br />";
echo $two;
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Bryan, yes, it's posible that way, but.. why you would use seven lines instead of just one ?

Comment: @Alegro I was making it easy for the user to understand.